# Setup PHP not working with HTML file

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I have a very basic HTML file, that displays some text, and includes a php file, which also echos very basic text:

My HTML code is in a file called home.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file is called footer.php:

```
<?php echo "<p>Test</p>"; ?>
```

I've installed XAMPP on my Windows machine, and the setup currently looks like:

[image]

I'm not too sure what the XAMPP setup entails, but all I do is double click on my html page in my local filesystem, and I see the html text being displayed, but not the PHP.

Is there anything left to do in my local setup to get PHP to work? Do I need to access my home.html webpage from a certain port? If so, how do I do that?

**EDIT**
I have pasted my home.html and footer.php files in C:\xampp\htdocs. My apache is running on port 80. How do I access the home.html? I have tried

> http://localhost:80/home.html

but that still doesn't show the php code

**EDIT2**
I changed my file name to home.php, and accessed it through localhost on port 80 and that seemed to work.

Comment: you have to put the html file in your apache htdocs directory (or whatever root dir you have) then run it from the browser by hitting (localhost/home.html

Comment: your 80 port is busy.

Comment: @AhmadHajjar Which root directory do you mean? The one where my home.html is? Or where the XAMPP setup is?

Comment: the one that you specify in your apache's config file `httpd.conf`

Comment: @AhmadHajjar How do I find out where the root dir is in httpd.conf? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: where did you install your apache?

Comment: @AhmadHajjar I've edited the question again with the solution. I think your answers helped me the most so if you include your response in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Don't forget to change the extension on home.html to home.php

Comment: I have done that thank you!

Comment: @Adam you are welcome .. dont mention it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double clicking will just open it in the browser as HTML and not process as PHP. It looks like Apache is running on port 80. Try these:

- http://127.0.0.1/
- http://localhost:80/

As others have pointed out, you also need to use the `.php` extension on your filename.

Also, make sure you are saving your file in the correct directory. It would be something like `C:/xampp/htdocs/`

Comment: This page just brings the XAMPP page, which shows that I've installed it. How do I access my home.html page?

Comment: rename the file to index.php

Comment: And how do I access a php file through a web browser?

Comment: if you use the filename index.php, Apache should know to automatically load it when you access the root of the directory. i.e. load http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: I've renamed my file to use .php, and loaded 127.0.0.1, but I'm just getting the Welcome to XAMPP page.

Comment: Then your file probably isnt saved to the correct directory. It should be something `C:/xampp/htdocs/` for xampp

Comment: I've copied the files in the correct htdocs repo. I've also edited the question, could you have a look please?

Comment: I've used yours and Ahmed's answers to achieve it. I'll accept yours for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to do `localhost` on your web browser

Answer (score 1):

For PHP functions you need to rename your file to home.php!

I hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the filename from home.html to home.php

If not, the php-interpreter is not able to process php-code

Comment: If he is double clicking the file it wont matter. It will just be processed by the browser as html. He needs to hit Apache first.

Comment: But I want my file to be HTML. How do I access a php page through a web browser?

Comment: @Adam the ending of the file doesn't matter. you can use html-code in a php-file, too. If you want to have .html in your browser adressline, than you should use mod_rewrite

Comment: @DanielSmith I agree with that.

Comment: How do you figure? Double clicking a PHP file from the filesystem will not open a browser window to the localhost path unless you have added some customizations to your filesystem.